# typo3 read single record from database table

Tags: database, typo3

I am trying to read a single record from my T3 DB table. I have the uid.

The documentation says:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyVendor\MyExtension\Domain\Repository;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

final class MySelectRepository
{
    private ConnectionPool $connectionPool;

    public function __construct(ConnectionPool $connectionPool)
    {
        $this->connectionPool = $connectionPool;
    }

    /**
     * @return array|false
     */
    public function selectSomeData()
    {
        $uid = 4;

        return $this->connectionPool
            ->getConnectionForTable('tt_content')
            ->select(
                ['uid', 'pid', 'bodytext'], // fields to select
                'tt_content',               // from
                ['uid' => $uid]             // where
            )
            ->fetchAssociative();
    }
}
```

I have included this into my Controller:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Averlon\AvVcard\Controller;

use Averlon\AvVcard\Domain\Model\Vcard;
use Averlon\AvVcard\Domain\Repository\VcardRepository;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Connection;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Page\PageRenderer;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\TypoScript\TypoScriptService;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Information\Typo3Version;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\FrontendConfigurationManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer;

use BK2K\BootstrapPackage\Service\IconService;
use BK2K\BootstrapPackage\Icons\IconProviderInterface;
use BK2K\BootstrapPackage\Icons\SvgIcon;

use TYPO3\TestingFramework\Core\Unit\UnitTestCase;
use TYPO3\TestingFramework\Fluid\Unit\ViewHelpers;

/**
 * This file is part of the "Averlon vCard Ex" Extension for TYPO3 CMS.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the
 * LICENSE.txt file that was distributed with this source code.
 *
 * (c) 2023
 */

/**
 * VcardController
 */
class VcardController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    private ConnectionPool $connectionPool;
    private const TABLE_NAME = 'tx_avvcard_domain_model_vcard';

    /**
     * Initializes the controller before invoking an action method.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function initializeAction()
    {
    }
    public function __construct(ConnectionPool $connectionPool)
    {
        $this->connectionPool = $connectionPool;
    }
    /**
     * action icon minimal
     *
     * @param \Averlon\AvVcard\Domain\Model\Vcard $vcard
     * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
     */
    public function iconAction(): \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
    {
        $xxRecord = $this->connectionPool
            ->getConnectionForTable(self::TABLE_NAME)
            ->select(
             ['uid'],
             self::TABLE_NAME,
             ['uid' => $this->settings['flexform']['vcardEntity']]
         )
         ->fetchAssociative();
        var_dump($xxRecord);

        return $this->htmlResponse();
    }

}
```

Once the fetch of the record works I will put the result into some varialbes to access them in my fluid template.

When processing the code I get the error in the FE:

```
Averlon\AvVcard\Controller\VcardController::__construct(): Argument #1 ($connectionPool) must be of type TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool
```

Any hint appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor required a instance of ConnectionPool as argument., but TYPO3 will create your class instance without any arguments.

The whole thing would work via the dependency injection, but that need a valid Services.yaml in your extension.
You can find a simple example in the TYPO3 documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html#id7

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  MyVendor\MyExtension\:
    resource: '../Classes/*'
    exclude: '../Classes/Domain/Model/*'
```

If you then delete the cache in the install tool, TYPO3 should pass the ConnectionPool in the constructor.

Alternatively, instead of passing the ConnectionPool in the constructor, you can simply use `GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable(..)` inside your method.

As addition, you should use `getQueryBuilderForTable()` instead of `getConnectionForTable()` as you cannot select anything on a connection. These methods are only available for a QueryBuilder instance.

Comment: services.yml exists already.
I am always irritated the documentation says something and experts say "you cannot ...".
I will try to follow you advise!

Comment: Please make sure that the filename ends with "yaml", not "yml". TYPO3 has choosen to use that suffix, which is the official one (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)

Comment: On case sensitive filesystems, the file should also start with upper case. "Services.yaml"

Comment: my fault. file is named: "Services.yaml" in Configuration.